# Add class in panels region

Tags: 7, panels, theming

I am trying this for long time. I am trying to add additional class in panels region. I am using panel page to display one of my node. I want to add region class but I am not getting success. Is there any way to achieve this? Is it possible to rewrite layout template in my theme? If so I can achieve this quickly. For example I wonder if it is possible to override layout template based on my node content type.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom layouts in your theme for panels, there's a fairly good how to guide here: https://drupal.org/node/495654

If you wanted to use different layouts for different nodes, you can add a variant to your panel pages, and under "selection rules, select "node:type" and select the content type you want. Then you can assign different panels layouts to each respective variant under the layout tab.

Comment: You can also use the [Panelizer](https://drupal.org/project/panelizer) module to easily change layouts and other Panels settings on a per node basis.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to change the markup and classes of Panel regions and panes without changing the entire layout, check out the following modules:

- [Clean Markup](https://drupal.org/project/clean_markup)

  > This module aims to clean up, enhance and facilitate the customization of markup for Drupal core and several popular contrib modules such as [Panels](https://drupal.org/project/panels).
- [Semantic Panels](https://drupal.org/project/semantic_panels)

  > It's a CTools style plugin that gives you full control over the HTML output of Panels panes.
  >   With it you can individually add/remove the:
  >
  > - Html element
  > - Classes
  > - Other attributes
  >
  > On the pane title, pane content, and pane wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem this morning, and after some googling found an answer.  It comes down to finding the right **tpl.php** file and copying it to your own theme.

If you're subtheming from a base theme (in my case, for example, adaptivetheme), the base theme may provide its own layouts.  Template files will be included there.  The base theme may also implement a `template_preprocess` function that you can use to add classes, if that's supported within the **.tpl.php**.

Panels ships with some built-in layouts.  I think that the template files located in the panels module directory under **plugins/layouts/<layout>/panels_<layout>.tpl.php** will be what your're looking for.  I haven't used them specifically, but they appear to follow the same pattern.

If you want to provide a different layout depending on node content type, however, you'd probably want to explore using panels page variants in the node_view panels page.  You can change layout and add pane-specific classes there through the UI.